# Confused about the variable type in Rack's source code

Tags: ruby, scope, rack

My question related to the following 3 code excerpt:

code of class method: `start(options = nil)`

```
# File 'lib/rack/server.rb', line 136

def self.start(options = nil)
  new(options).start
end
```

code of instance method: `#initialize(options = nil)`

```
# File 'lib/rack/server.rb', line 174
def initialize(options = nil)
  @options = options
  @app = options[:app] if options && options[:app]
end
```

code of instance method: `#start`

```
# File 'lib/rack/server.rb', line 229
def start
  if options[:warn]
    $-w = true
  end

  ...# more lines that are not related to my question
end
```

my question is that Should  the the local variable `options` in the instance method `start` be `@options`?. In my option,as the first 2 excerpts shows that the options as parameter that pass to `initialize`, and make it to a instance variable `@options`, so in the instance method start, it should reference it as `@options`, instead of `options`, because the scope of `options` can't be accessed by  #start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same class there are getter method for options:

```
# File 'lib/rack/server.rb', line 180
def options
  @options ||= parse_options(ARGV)
end
```

`options` in `#start` is a call to this method, not a local variable.

Comment: Thanks again for answering my question, it's so satisfying for me to figure it out!